# How to upload image to wordpress from external page

Tags: wp-api

I have a webpage on localhost that do not have wordpress environment, I had use woocommerce api to create the product, however woocommerce api doesnt seem to upload the image.
I want to create the product and upload the image.
this the code I am using and the woocommerce api default.

```php
<?php
$data = [
    'name' => 'Premium Quality',
    'type' => 'simple',
    'regular_price' => '21.99',
    'description' => 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.',
    'short_description' => 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.',
    'categories' => [
        [
            'id' => 9
        ],
        [
            'id' => 14
        ]
    ],
    'images' => [
        [
            'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_front.jpg'
        ],
        [
            'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_back.jpg'
        ]
    ]
];

print_r($woocommerce->post('products', $data));
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make sure: You have a local environment, without WooCommerce, from which you want to create a product in your WooCommerce Wordpress site, and make sure that the images you provide are uploaded to your WordPress site.

## 1. Install library

Make sure that you in your local environment have installed the [WooCommerce REST API PHP Library](https://github.com/woocommerce/wc-api-php).

```sh
composer require automattic/woocommerce
```

## 2. Create your script

Create a file called `my_import_file.php`

```sh
touch my_import_file.php
```

Edit that file with your favorite editor (or any editor).

Using **Vim**

```sh
vim my_import_file.php
```

Using **Visual Studio Code** (if you have the [shell command installed](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_launching-from-the-command-line))

```sh
code my_import_file.php
```

You need to:

- [Generate keys to the REST API](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/) of your WooCommerce installation.
- [Generate an application password](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/05/application-passwords-integration-guide/) for this import script.

Your file should look similar to this:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Settings
 */
// Your Wordpress site URL
DEFINE('WORDPRESS_BASE_URL', 'https://enter-your-wordpress-url-here');

// Your WordPress username
DEFINE('WORDPRESS_LOGIN', 'enter-your-wordpress-username-here');

// Create a new Application Password in dashboard /wp-admin/profile.php
DEFINE('WORDPRESS_APPLICATION_PASSWORD', 'enter-your-application-password-here');

// Create a new REST API key from your wordpress installation
// https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/
DEFINE('WOOCOMMERCE_CONSUMER_KEY', 'enter-your-woocomemrce-consumer-key-here');
DEFINE('WOOCOMMERCE_CONSUMER_SECRET', 'enter-your-woocomemrce-consumer-secret-here');

// Load composers autoload
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// Use the WooComerce client
use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;

// Initiate the WooCommerce client
$woocommerce = new Client(
    WORDPRESS_BASE_URL,
    WOOCOMMERCE_CONSUMER_KEY,
    WOOCOMMERCE_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    [
        'version' => 'wc/v3',
    ]
);


// An array of all the images you want to upload. They can be local files or URL's.
// Any non existing images will be filtered out.
$images = array(
    "/Users/admin/Documents/nice-image-of-me.jpg",
    "http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_back.jpg",
    "string that is invalid"
);


// Define the product you want to create
$data = [
    'name' => 'Premium Quality',
    'type' => 'simple',
    'regular_price' => '21.99',
    'description' => 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.',
    'short_description' => 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.',
    'categories' => [
        [
            'id' => 9
        ],
        [
            'id' => 14
        ]
    ],
    'images' => prepare_array_of_images_for_wordpress($images)

];

// Create the product
$result = $woocommerce->post('products', $data);

// Print the result
print_r($result);




/**
 * Takes an array of images, strings or URL's and prepares for import.
 */
function prepare_array_of_images_for_wordpress(array $array_of_images){
    // Create empty array
    $images_to_upload = array();

    // Loop through the input, and process each entry
    foreach($array_of_images as $image){
        $images_to_upload[] = file_or_url_to_wordpress_image($image);
    }

    // Remove any unsucessful images from the array.
    return array_filter($images_to_upload);
}



/**
 * Takes a file or a url and uploads it to WordPress
 * Returns the image ID from the WordPress media gallery.
 */
function file_or_url_to_wordpress_image($image_path){

    // If the input is a URl, we can process it
    if (filter_var($image_path, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
        return ['src'=>$image_path];
    }

     // Make sure the image exist
    if (!file_exists($image_path)){return;}

    // Load the image
    $file = file_get_contents( $image_path );

    // Get the filename
    $filename = basename($image_path);

    // Initiate curl.
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, WORDPRESS_BASE_URL .'/wp-json/wp/v2/media/' );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; filename=\"$filename\"",
        'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode( WORDPRESS_LOGIN. ':' . WORDPRESS_APPLICATION_PASSWORD ),
    ] );
    $result = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    // Decode the response
    $api_response = json_decode($result);

    // Return the ID of the image that is now uploaded to the WordPress site.
    return ['id' => $api_response->id];
}
```

If you want to specify each image manually, you replace this line:

```php
    'images' => prepare_array_of_images_for_wordpress($images)
```

With

```php
    'images' => [
        [
            'id' => file_or_url_to_wordpress_image('path-to-image'),
            'other_option' => 'value'
        ],
        [
            'src' => file_or_url_to_wordpress_image('url-to-image'),
            'other_option' => 'value'
        ],
    ]
```

Just make sure you use `'id'` if referring to an uploaded image, and `'src'` when it's a URL.

## 3. Run the script

Either in a browser, or from the command line using the following command:

```sh
php my_import_file.php
```

It should output something like this:

```sh
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 736
    [name] => Premium Quality
    [slug] => premium-quality
    [permalink] => https://localhost/p/uncategorized/premium-quality/
    [date_created] => 2021-06-12T18:01:08
    [date_created_gmt] => 2021-06-12T18:01:08
    [date_modified] => 2021-06-12T18:01:08
    [date_modified_gmt] => 2021-06-12T18:01:08
    [type] => simple
    [status] => publish
    [featured] => 
    [catalog_visibility] => visible
    [description] => Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.
    [short_description] => Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
    [sku] => 
    [price] => 21.99
    [regular_price] => 21.99
    [sale_price] => 
    [date_on_sale_from] => 
    [date_on_sale_from_gmt] => 
    [date_on_sale_to] => 
    [date_on_sale_to_gmt] => 
    [on_sale] => 
    [purchasable] => 1
    [total_sales] => 0
    [virtual] => 
    [downloadable] => 
    [downloads] => Array
        (
        )

    [download_limit] => -1
    [download_expiry] => -1
    [external_url] => 
    [button_text] => 
    [tax_status] => taxable
    [tax_class] => 
    [manage_stock] => 
    [stock_quantity] => 
    [backorders] => no
    [backorders_allowed] => 
    [backordered] => 
    [low_stock_amount] => 
    [sold_individually] => 
    [weight] => 
    [dimensions] => stdClass Object
        (
            [length] => 
            [width] => 
            [height] => 
        )

    [shipping_required] => 1
    [shipping_taxable] => 1
    [shipping_class] => 
    [shipping_class_id] => 0
    [reviews_allowed] => 1
    [average_rating] => 0
    [rating_count] => 0
    [upsell_ids] => Array
        (
        )

    [cross_sell_ids] => Array
        (
        )

    [parent_id] => 0
    [purchase_note] => 
    [categories] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 27
                    [name] => Mat
                    [slug] => mat
                )

        )

    [tags] => Array
        (
        )

    [images] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 734
                    [date_created] => 2021-06-12T18:01:07
                    [date_created_gmt] => 2021-06-12T18:01:07
                    [date_modified] => 2021-06-12T18:01:07
                    [date_modified_gmt] => 2021-06-12T18:01:07
                    [src] => https://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/nice-image-of-me.jpg
                    [name] => nice-image-of-me
                    [alt] => 
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 735
                    [date_created] => 2021-06-12T18:01:08
                    [date_created_gmt] => 2021-06-12T18:01:08
                    [date_modified] => 2021-06-12T18:01:08
                    [date_modified_gmt] => 2021-06-12T18:01:08
                    [src] => https://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/T_2_back-3.jpg
                    [name] => T_2_back-3.jpg
                    [alt] => 
                )

        )

    [attributes] => Array
        (
        )

    [default_attributes] => Array
        (
        )

    [variations] => Array
        (
        )

    [grouped_products] => Array
        (
        )

    [menu_order] => 0
    [price_html] => <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>21,99&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&euro;</span></bdi></span>
    [related_ids] => Array
        (
            [0] => 143
            [1] => 687
            [2] => 17
            [3] => 712
            [4] => 688
        )

    [meta_data] => Array
        (
        )

    [stock_status] => instock
    [brands] => Array
        (
        )

    [_links] => stdClass Object
        (
            [self] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [href] => https://localhost/wp-json/wc/v3/products/736
                        )

                )

            [collection] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [href] => https://localhost/wp-json/wc/v3/products
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: This works perfectly when I use a link from an online image, it also uploads the image to wp library, however when I change that link to one path of my computer, it does not it throws an php error and do not load.     error: Invalid URL Provided. [woocommerce_product_image_upload_error].

Comment: Ah. Yes, I see the problem.

The reason it doesn't work with a path, is that you're not really passing the image, you're just telling WooCommerce where to find it, and as the server does not have a way to see things on your local computer, there is no way the server can download the files.

I'll see if I can put together a solution for this case. But if you want to get it done straight away, you could always just upload the local files to your server, and then use the url of the images instead of the local filename when passing it in your function.

Comment: exactly like so, my custom platform has several thousand products, and like this I would just insert the image location and automatically create the product on this wordpress website.      I have been searching on how to do it since this morning, that for me was almost 7 hours ago...

Comment: Now it's updated and does exactly what you were looking for. As a bonus, I added the possibility to pass both local files and URL's into the import.

Answer (score 0):

I had achieve it by using I suspect the wp_api:

```php
$img = 'C:/wamp64/www/leiria/img/2.1.jpg';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example-site.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/' );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents( $img ) );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Content-Disposition: form-data; filename="file_example_name.jpg"',
        'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode( 'wordpress_username:wordpress_password"' ), ] );
$result = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );




echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```