# upload image to wp-api

Tags: wp-api

I am using a localhost external website, that isn't wordpress related, and I want to upload an image to wordpress, possibly needs to be with wordpress api, however I would like to know how to connect to wordpress api and upload the image selected using if possible php or javascript.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload image to wordpress from external page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/390452/how-to-upload-image-to-wordpress-from-external-page)

Comment: yes it does, thanks!